# Can I set the "HTML" Title of a PDF file served by my Apache Web server

Tags: apache, http-headers

I have HTML pages that contain <a> tags with hrefs that point to PDF files. My Apache Web server serves them just fine, but the title, as shown in the Browser history, is of the file name. I would like to be able to set that title.

Perhaps there's a Header than can be set?

I don't want to write a script to serve the files as the server can handle Content-Encoding negotiation (e.g., for gzip), and do flow control, none of such do I want to re-create.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an http header you can set.

```
Content-Disposition:inline; filename="*File name you want*";
```

Comment: This sets the file name when you download it, not the title that is shown in chrome/firefox.

Answer (score 2):

I created a PHP-Skript (e.g. download.php, filename doesn't matter) like this:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.addslashes($_REQUEST['title']).'"'); //filename doesn't set the browser title here, only when page is saved/downloaded
$content = file_get_contents($_REQUEST['filename']);
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($content));
echo $content;
```

In my setup (Windows 10; Apache 2.4.37; PHP 7.1.25) you can now do a request like this:
http://..../download.php/browser_title?filename=test.pdf

I tested this successfully in Chrome and Firefox.
Internet Explorer was not able to display a PDF-Document inline :-/.
Microsoft Edge also included the URL-Parameter in the title bar :-(.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue you are having is that the client browser is storing the file name in the history, which you cannot fix.

Last I checked, the title in the history came from the  setting of the HTML page (not a header), so there should be no HTTP header field for the title.

I am no HTTP expert and do not know all the fields, but I do not remember there being a setting in any server that I have ever worked with to set the page's title (just the status code, protocol, etc.)

Comment: Right -- the name in the History would be the page title. But the link that's being GET'd is for a static asset (a PDF file), not an HTML file, so there's no way to set a TITLE tag in the (non-existent) Head section.

Actually - Safari (which I use) shows in the history "(no title)".

Comment: As I said, the title in the History is the <title> child of the HTML head section. From looking at the HTTP headers, there is no way to set the title of a page. If you want to have a PDF title to show up the in  history, you would need a browser that can look into a PDF and render its title.