# Setting the Title of a Tab in a browser when using PDF content type

Tags: c#, .net, browser, cross-browser

We have a scenario where we request a report via a HTTP handler.

The HttResponse ContentType is PDF if the report was generated. If there is an error generating the report the result is a HTML document describing the error condition.

How does one associate the text that appears in the tab in Internet Explorer to the HTTPResponse. Currently it shows the request URL twice after the report is generated? If the report generation results in an error the title from the resulting HTML ContentType is displayed in the Tab. On subsequent successful attempts to generate the report the Title from the previous attempt is being displayed. To fix this problem the IE cache is cleared and the Tab title comes back.

We ideally want to display the report name in the tab not the request URL.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and I've come to conclusion that it can't be done.

I use Java EE, but it's not relevant though as it's all about HTTP and browser implementation. What you get depends on the user agent.

There are a couple of work-arounds by using either an IFrame or embedded object element, but both have drawbacks. Mainly error handling is problematic as the pdf content is downloaded in a different GET request than the parent document. Of course the Content-Type would not be pdf anymore.

Related question: [Can I set the “HTML” Title of a PDF file served by my Apache Web server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5667576/1312559)